# Multivariate multiple regression in SAS

Tags: r, sas

Suppose I want perform a multivariate multiple regression analysis
and test (using a single test) the hypothesis, that the regression parameters for two explanatory variables are 0.

In `R` I would do the following:
(Assuming thedata is a data.frame with column names x1 x2 (for the DVs) and x3 x4 (for the IVs)

```
fit = manova(cbind(x1,x2) ~ cbind(x3,x4),data=thedata)  
summary(fit)
```

This gives me Pillais' trace and the associated approx. F 
My question is: What procedure would produce the same analysis in `SAS`?
I have tried variations of the following invocation of GLM:

```
PROC GLM DATA=thedata;
MODEL x1 x2 = x3 x4 /SS3 NOUNI;
MANOVA H=_ALL_;
RUN;
```

But I can't seem to get beyond testing for x3 and x4 separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question using `PROC REG`:

```
PROC REG DATA=thedata;
MODEL x1 x2 = x3 x4;
MTEST x3,x4;
RUN;
```

Furthermore, a user in the SAS forums pointed this solution to me:

```
PROC GLM DATA=thedata;
MODEL x1 x2 = x3 x4;
CONTRAST 'All Zero' x3 1,x4 1;
MANOVA;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PROC GLM DATA=thedata;
MODEL x1 x2 = x3 x4 /SS3 NOUNI;
MANOVA H=_ALL_/PRINTE PRINTH;
RUN;
```

Comment: The E matrix in SAS will give me right Error matrix, and I could in principle compute Pillais trace using the E matrix from the E matrix by running GLM with MODEL x1 x2 = /SS3 NOUNI; since this the H matrix I'm looking for. But I'm looking for a way to make SAS perform this calculation.

Comment: I don't know how to do that; it should be possible and may even be already done, but I haven't seen it.